# maximizing function using optim in r where one of the parameters is an integer

Tags: r, r-optimization

I have a function that I need to maximize that contains 3 parameters, one of which is an integer.

How do I let the optim function know to maximize (instead of minimize which is the default).
And how do I let it know that one of the parameters in an integer?

Will it work if one of the parameters is a binary or categorical?

Comment: To maximize your function, define a new objective function that returns the negative of your objective.

Answer (score 3):

Max vs min is easy (set `fnscale=-1` in the `control` parameter).

Integer parameters are *not* easy. Such problems are called *mixed integer programming* problems and most available methods only handle mixed *linear* or *quadratic* problems. From the [Optimization Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html):

> MIP (Mixed integer programming and its variants MILP for LP and MIQP for QP, 90C11): glpkAPI, lpSolve, lpSolveAPI, Rcplex, Rglpk, Rmosek, Rsymphony

(I'm not very familiar with these methods.)

Most of the methods implemented in `optim` assume continuous parameter spaces. (`method="SANN"` will work since you can give it explicit rules for updating - see the examples - but it's tricky to get it to work efficiently.) Most of the optimizers listed in the [Optimization Task View](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) are for continuous optimization - the section on global/stochastic gives the most options for mixed discrete/continuous problems.

If the range of plausible integers is reasonably small you can use brute force (i.e., optimize over the two continuous parameters for each of a range of fixed integer values); you could also use bisection search over the integers.